# Recycler view: no adapter attached; skipping layout(Error in recycler view for API )

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, adapter

This is the recycler view activity. Here I have initialized the recycler view. Despite that I am getting error. Where might have I gone wrong. In the log cat I get the error

`No adapter attached; skipping layout`.

Here I am getting response display the response in the recycler view using APIs. I am also using retrofit too. In the `get data()` function I am taking the response status and getting data.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ListAdapter1 listAdapter;
//    List<SupermarketModels> supermarketModelsList = new ArrayList<>();
    ApiInterface apiInterface;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initialization();
        getdata();
    }

    private void initialization(){
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        Retrofit retrofit = APIClient.getclient();
        apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    }

    private void setadapter(List<SupermarketModels> supermarketModels){

        listAdapter = new ListAdapter1(this, supermarketModels);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
    private void getdata(){
        apiInterface.getList().enqueue(new Callback<GetListResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetListResponse> call, Response<GetListResponse> response) {

                try {
                    if (response!= null){
                        if (response.body().getStatus().equals("1")){
                            setadapter(response.body().getData());


                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("exp", e.getLocalizedMessage());

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetListResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to `setOrientation()` to your layout manager.and remove `notifyDataSetChanged()` line from there.

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL); //or HORIZONTLE,whatever you want
    
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    
            recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //remove this line from here
```

Comment: Did that. Still getting same error. `No adapter attached; skipping layout`

Comment: try with add this line,may this helfull `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` before set adapter

Answer (score 0):

This error can be avoid setting empty adapter first before setting actual adapter, when data is actually loading. In your example before calling `getdata()` you just call empty adapter like this

```
EmptyAdapter emptyAdapter = new EmptyAdapter();
recyclerView.setAdapter(emptyAdapter);
```

Here is Empty Adapter class , which you need to create

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class EmptyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EmptyAdapter.EmptyHolder> {
@Override
public EmptyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EmptyHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

class EmptyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public EmptyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I did this. But still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you set adapter before your getdata(); ? I checked but not got error.

Comment: yes. I did that. Still getting error. I typed `recyclerView.setAdapter(emptyAdapter);` in between `initialization();` and `getData()`